# RocksDB: how to use ttl in java?

Tags: rocksdb

I am testing rocksdb for java api. I put a key-value entry into the map, and then wait for 20s, then get from map. Why the entry is not deleted? 
this is my code:

```
import org.rocksdb.Options;
import org.rocksdb.RocksDBException;
import org.rocksdb.TtlDB;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TtlDB.loadLibrary();
        Options options = new Options()
                .setCreateIfMissing(true);


        TtlDB db = TtlDB.open(options, args[0],20,false);
        if(args.length > 3 && "put".equals(args[1])) {
            db.put(args[2].getBytes(), args[3].getBytes());
        }

        byte[] arr = db.get(args[2].getBytes());
        if(arr != null) {
            System.out.println(new String(arr));
        } else {
            System.out.println(arr);
        }
        System.out.println(db.get(args[2].getBytes()));
        Thread.sleep(21000);
        System.out.println(db.get(args[2].getBytes()));
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699784/how-to-set-ttl-on-rocks-db-properly for pointers to the relevant sources

Answer (score 0):

Expired TTL values are deleted in compaction only:(Timestamp + ttl < time_now)

https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Time-to-Live